# Procedualy Generateing Terrain in Blender Game Engine

Tags: python, python-3.x, game-engine, blender

I am making an first-person open-world game in Blender Game Engine(bge), and intend to have the terrain be generated procedurally. I have looked around from website to website, and have only found various ways for the game to generate terrain in the "edit" mode, but not a way to generate it in blender game engine, eg. I would like it so that every time you play, the terrain is different. Is there any way to do this with python code, or at all?
Thanks in advance for your help!

Note: When I say procedual, I do not mean for the world to be infinitely large, eg Minecraft(although acquiring a solution that supported that would be awesome)

Answer (score 0):

Procedurally generating terrain on the fly is not that easy, but it is possible. You must create the terrain mesh with its triangles and textures during runtime and then dynamically load/unload the parts the player can see.

So you would not create a single big landmass, but rather divide your terrain in smaller chunks than you can load and unload as needed. To create the actual terrain you could use a height-map or a noise algorithm.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I already know the basic ideas behind Procedualy generateing terreign, but was wondering if/how it can be done in blender.